# TreeView has stop working when click on the root of the treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

the error happen when  click on the root of the treeview.

how to fix this problem.

I upload this project on 2shared.com

this project on 2shared.com

[download here](http://www.2shared.com/file/Rqh90u3m/ExTreeview.html)

this is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ExTreeview.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExTreeview"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="LocationTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding SubLocation}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyLocation}">
        <TextBlock>for root</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:house}" > <!-- object from house class use this DataTemplate-->
        <StackPanel Margin="0,70,0,0">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"> ชื่อ</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                ความจุ(ตัว)
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"> สถานะ</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"> หมายเหตุ</TextBlock>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path=name}"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtCapacity" Text="{Binding Path=capacity}">

                </TextBox>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="cmbStatus"  >
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding status}" />
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="txtComment" Text="{Binding Path=comment}"></TextBox>

            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Location}" > <!-- object from Location class use this DataTemplate-->
        <StackPanel Margin="0,70,0,0" >

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"> ชื่อ</TextBlock>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"> สถานะ</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"> หมายเหตุ</TextBlock>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path=name}"></TextBox>


                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="cmbStatus"  >
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding status}" />
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="txtComment" Text="{Binding Path=comment}"></TextBox>

            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:zone}"> <!-- object from zone class use this DataTemplate-->
        <StackPanel Margin="0,70,0,0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TreeView1, Path=SelectedItem}">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"> ชื่อ</TextBlock>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"> สถานะ</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"> หมายเหตุ</TextBlock>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path=name}"></TextBox>


                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="cmbStatus"  >
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding status}" />
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="txtComment" Text="{Binding Path=comment}"></TextBox>

            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="450" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="TreeView1" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="ทั้งหมด" Name="TreeviewRootNode" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource LocationTemplate}">
        </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="นำไปใช้งาน" Height="30" Width="80" />
        <Button Content="ยกเลิก" Height="30" Margin="15" Width="50" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>


    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=TreeView1, Path=SelectedItem}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">

    </ContentControl>

</Grid>
```

here cs file of the xaml

namespace ExTreeview
{

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyLocation locationList = new MyLocation();

        Location location1 = new Location();
        location1.name = "ฟาร์มชัยภูมิ";
        location1.id = "01";
        location1.comment = "คอมเม้น";
        location1.status = "ใช้งาน";
        location1.SubLocation = new List<zone>();

        List<house> sub1 = new List<house>();
        sub1.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือน ช11", capacity = "50,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        sub1.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือน ช12", capacity = "30,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        location1.SubLocation.Add(new zone() { name = "โซน ช1", SubLocation = sub1, status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });

        List<house> sub2 = new List<house>();
        sub2.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือน ช21", capacity = "80,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        sub2.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือน ช22", capacity = "50,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        location1.SubLocation.Add(new zone() { name = "โซน ช2", SubLocation = sub2, status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });

        Location location2 = new Location();
        location2.name = "ฟาร์มนครนายก";
        location2.SubLocation = new List<zone>();

        List<house> sub3 = new List<house>();
        List<house> sub4 = new List<house>();
        List<house> sub6 = new List<house>();
        sub3.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือนย่อย นย1", capacity = "50,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        sub3.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือนย่อย นย2", capacity = "60,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        sub4.Add(new house() { name = "โซนย่อย นย1", SubLocation = sub3, status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });


        sub4.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือน น11", capacity = "50,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        sub4.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือน น12", capacity = "40,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });


        location2.SubLocation.Add(new zone() { name = "โซน น1", SubLocation=sub4, status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });

        List<house> sub5 = new List<house>();
        sub5.Add(new house() { name = "โรงเรือน น21", capacity = "30,000", status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });
        location2.SubLocation.Add(new zone() { name = "โซน น2", SubLocation = sub5, status = "ใช้งาน", comment = "comment" });

        locationList.Add(location1);
        locationList.Add(location2);

        TreeviewRootNode.ItemsSource = locationList;

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

here Location class

namespace ExTreeview
{

```
public class Location
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public string id { set; get; }
    public string status { set; get; }
    public string comment { set; get; }

    public List<zone> SubLocation { set; get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (this.name);
    }

}
public class zone : Location
{
    public string capacity { set; get; }
    public List<house> SubLocation { set; get; }
    public List<house> SubLocationZ { set; get; }
}

public class house : Location
{
    public string capacity { set; get; }
    public List<house> SubLocation { set; get; }
}

public class MyLocation : List<Location> { }


}
```

help me please.
I'm try to fix this over 2 day.
thank for help me.

Comment: this project on 2shared.com

http://www.2shared.com/file/Rqh90u3m/ExTreeview.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the explicit root `TreeViewItem` and by the `ContentControl` which is bound to the TreeView's `SelectedItem`.

When you select the root, the binding tries to make the treeview's root item (which is `TreeViewItem`) as a logical child of the `ContentControl`. Because in WPF an element can be only a logical child of one another element and because your root item is already the child of the treeview you get the exception:

> Specified element is already the logical child of another element.
>   Disconnect it first.

If you select any other node it works because in these cases the `SelectedItem` is not a `TreeViewItem` but an instance of your `Location` class.

To make it work you should create your root node in code instead of XAML:

```
public class Root
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public MyLocation Locations { get; set; } 
}
```

Instead of `TreeviewRootNode.ItemsSource = locationList;`:

```
var root = new Root() { Locations = locationList, name = "ทั้งหมด" };
TreeView1.ItemsSource = new List<Root> { root };
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="TreeView1" 
      ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource RootTemplate}" />
```

DataTemplates:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="RootTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"  
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LocationTemplate}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<!--Empty DataTemplate to display the root when selected-->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Root}" />
```

Comment: I'am newbie in wpf. and in Thai wpf is less resource for TUT. very thankssss

Comment: I'm glad that it solved your problem. You can always [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) even with rep 1.